# Как в mongodb удалить последние несколько записей?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Есть коллекция, в каждой записи есть поле time. Мне нужно из нее удалять лишь последние например 10 записей, как мне это сделать? 
Мои попытки

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').remove({name:'Валли'}).sort({time:-1}).limit(10)
```

Тут разумеется ошибка в том что у remove нет метода sort.
d

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').findAndModify({query: { 'name':'Валли' },sort: { 'time': -1 },limit: 10,remove: true} )
```

так была ошибка в том что я удалил все записи ибо limit тут не работает=)
Были и другие попытки, но они слишком тупые что бы сюда их вообще отражать=)
Еще раз повторю вопрос как мне удалить самые старые 10 записей из коллекции(ищем по полю name, сортируем по полю time, удаляем заданное количество записей)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать `limit()` для методов `remove()` или `findAndModify()`.
Удалить нужные документы из коллекции можно в два этапа.

1) Вернуть массив из `_id` элементов которые вам необходимо удалить.

```
db.collectionName.find({name:'Валли'}, {_id : 1})
.limit(10)
.sort({time:-1})
.toArray()
.map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });
```

2) Присвоить массив например переменной `removeIdsArray` и передать в метод `remove()`.

```
db.collectionName.remove({_id: {$in: removeIdsArray}});
```

Comment: Так не интересно) Но все равно спасибо, буду знать что нельзя)